# How to let FB test login before it goes live?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm setting up facebook login for my website. I've got it working w/ a test app on my dev server.  I'm getting ready to ask facebook for approval, but there's something I can't figure out.  They want instructions on how to access facebook login on my site. It says:

> Please provide step-by-step instructions in English that show how to access Facebook Login.

Well the problem is you can't get to facebook login on my site right now. I'm not going to add that functionality to my live site when my app still isn't approved.  Anyone know how to deal with this? Do I have to give facebook access to my dev site? And point dev to the production app?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs to be able to test it for review, so there must be a way to access it for them.

That being said, why do you even want to go through the review process? You only need to go through review if you need additional permissions. A basic login does not need to get approved.

You can read all about review in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review